# .net core published single file spamming "Config reload token fired. Checking for changes..." in log file

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

At the beginning I am published my .NET core API project to Linux environment. When I using service file execute my WebApplication2.dll, the log is normal without spamming message after started the service.

But once I changed published single file:
[image]
[image]

It's start spamming message "Config reload token fired. Checking for changes..." after started the service

[image]

**Program.cs**

```
    using NLog.Web;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: i disable read config from linux instead of i read while loading i create singleton for all services. If you run the application under systemd specific working directory and set permissions

Comment: @CarlosCocom Can i get more details about it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

im some busy but in resumen in program.cs, AppSettings is a dto

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    var oSettings = GetSettings();
     ...
    //other services
 }


private static AppSettings GetSettings()
{
    var appSettingLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);            

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appSettingLocation)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);

    IConfiguration config = builder.Build();

    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    config.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);

    return appSettings;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am still prefer using Nlog to log message in file format.